# Hibernate: update table query is not working

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, entitymanager

I have a query

```java
     public void saveReportId(BigDecimal reportId) {
               entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE ReportEntity r set r.report_id = reportId WHERE s.phase = :phase")
                       .setParameter("reportId", reportId)
                       .setParameter("phase", ReportStatus.NEW.getValue())
                       .executeUpdate();
      }
```

But instead of populating the table with value of the reportId that I pass in the argument I've got an error :

```
Problem compiling - The state field cannot be resolved.
```

Comment: Is this the full error message ? Also shouldn't it be `:reportId` ?

Comment: It was full msg - and that work :) Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Missing `:reportId` and also replace `s.phase` to `r.phase` . Just update it :

```
entityManager.createQuery("update ReportEntity r set r.report_id = :reportId where r.phase = :phase")
                           .setParameter("reportId", reportId)
                           .setParameter("phase", ReportStatus.NEW.getValue())
                           .executeUpdate();
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In your named parameter query, you may be missed to follow the rule i.e `... condition= :paramName`. 
So, in your case, just take care of your `reportId` parameter. Just change your second like this:

```
entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE ReportEntity r set r.report_id = :reportId WHERE s.phase = :phase")
```